# Problem about making my code stop the current function if it detects a non accepted value

Tags: python

I’m currently trying to solve a problem in which you are given an Int number, that number dictates the amount of inputs you need. The goal is to determine the temperature in two zones of a barn. There are 3 thermometers in the room, so if for example the first input = 1 you need to ask for three letters (one for each thermometer) and 3 temperatures (one for each too). There are only 3 accepted value for the letters so, if a different one is entered the program should send an error code and not calculate the average temperature of the room. This is the code I have. I already solved everything, but I need to find a way in which if a wrong letter is typed, the program will just skip the calculation of those three values. Idk if you are going to understand my question, I’ve just started coding, so any help is highly appreciated. If you do not understand my question I will gladly try to explain it better. Thanks
My code:

```
mediciones = int(input())
input()
numero_de_medicion = 0

def cambio(T1, porcentaje):
    Zona = Temp + Temp * (porcentaje)
    return Zona

def promedio(Z,T2):
    temp = (Z+T2)/2
    return temp

def sumar(n):
    numero = n+1
    return numero    

for termometro in range(mediciones):
    for medicion in range(3):
        Zona = input()
        Tempo = input()
        try:
            Temp = float(Tempo)
            esa = True
        except:
            print(f'invalid temperature {Tempo}')
            esa = False
        if Zona == 'E':
            TempE = cambio (Temp, 0.025)
        elif Zona == 'C':
            TempC = cambio(Temp, -0.15)
        elif Zona == 'O':
            TempO = Temp
        else:
            print('invalid sensor F')
            
    numero_de_medicion +=1
    
         
    if True:
        zona1= promedio(TempO,TempC)
        zona2= promedio(TempC,TempE)
        
        print(f'{numero_de_medicion}: {zona1:.2f} {zona2:.2f}')
```

Comment: try to make your posts as short and concise as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding properly, what you want to check if the zone is correct.

You should do this:

```
mediciones = int(input())
input()
numero_de_medicion = 0

def cambio(T1, porcentaje):
    Zona = Temp + Temp * (porcentaje)
    return Zona

def promedio(Z,T2):
    temp = (Z+T2)/2
    return temp

def sumar(n):
    numero = n+1
    return numero    

for termometro in range(mediciones):
    for medicion in range(3):
        def result():
            if True:
                zona1= promedio(TempO,TempC)
                zona2= promedio(TempC,TempE)
                print(f'{numero_de_medicion}: {zona1:.2f} {zona2:.2f}')

        Zona = input()
        Tempo = input()
        try:
            Temp = float(Tempo)
            esa = True
        except:
            print(f'invalid temperature {Tempo}')
            esa = False
        if Zona == 'E':
            TempE = cambio (Temp, 0.025)
            result()
        elif Zona == 'C':
            TempC = cambio(Temp, -0.15)
            result()
        elif Zona == 'O':
            TempO = Temp
            result()
        else:
            print('invalid sensor F')
            
    numero_de_medicion +=1
```

Is this what you want to do? Please let me know so I can find a better solution

Comment: In the code above I am just making the print of the result a function so you can call it only if the condition of the letters is valid.

Comment: Thank you, what I need to make with the code is that when it detects that a letter is not one of the accepted ones or the value of temperature can not be converted to a float the program will discard the calculations belonging to that set of three inputs.

Comment: Also, when I ran your code I got line 22, in result
    zona1= promedio(TempO,TempC)
NameError: name 'TempO' is not defined. Did you mean: 'Tempo'?  Not really sure why

Comment: This is with my current code:
Your Output (stdout)
1: 28.48 22.10
invalid sensor F
2: 26.48 24.00 (I have to get rid of this one since one of the letters is invalid)
3: 27.82 25.06
Expected Output
1: 28.48 22.10
invalid sensor F
2: 27.82 25.06

Comment: What do you want to get as output?

Comment: The input is the thermometer then the temperature. So, what I am required to do is to calculate the average temperature between two thermometers, but if the letter of one of the thermometers is invalid, the set of data belonging two that set of three thermometers and three temperatures should not be used to calculate the averages.

Comment: It is basically, how can I make my program discard that set of data when it detects an invalid input.